# Sources on revoking or annulling rabbinic semichah

Tags: sources-mekorot, rabbis, semicha, responsa

I’m looking for sources discussing whether or not rabbinic semichah can be revoked (and if it can, on what grounds), plus sources - especially responsa - which deal with specific cases. The main one I’ve found so far is Chatam Sofer CM162. Can anyone suggest any others?
(NB I’m specifically interested in rabbis rather than cantors, judges etc.)